# Edit an array with multiple callbacks and wait until they have all finished

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am replacing my Sqlite database with an online database (Firestore). For that each answer of the database comes back to me by callback.

The problem is that I have several calls to the database in a loop that filled a table and that the table is not accesible unless I declare it in the end and therefore I can not change it.

So I'm looking for a way to fill this table without completely modifying the code that already exists. I saw the `ArrayBlockingQueue` but I wonder if a simpler solution does not exist.

If possible I would like to keep all the variables inside the function but I have not yet found a solution for that.

I know that for this example we do not necessarily need a table but I want to keep it because it's just an example ;)

**Before (SQLite)**

```
public int player_in_x_game(int id_player) {

    int gamesWherePlayerIsHere = 0;
    ArrayList<Games> gamesArray = Database.getGamesArray();

    for (Game game: gamesArray)
        if(Utils.isPlayerPresentInGame(game.getId(), idPlayer))
            gamesWherePlayerIsHere++;

    return gamesWherePlayerIsHere;
}
```

**After (with callbacks)**

```
private static  int counter= 0;
private static  int resultNP = 0;
private static ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> results;

public static void numberGamesWherePlayerIsPresent(final long idPlayer, final Callbacks.IntCallback callback){
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            games(new Callbacks.ListGameCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCallback(ArrayList<Game> gameArrayList) {
                    counterNumberGamesWherePlayerIsPresent= gameArrayList.size();
                    results = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(gameArrayList.size());
                    for (Game game: gameArrayList){
                            Utils.isPlayerPresentInGame(game.getId(), idPlayer, new Callbacks.BooleanCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCallback(boolean bool) {
                                    if (bool)
                                        results.add(1);
                                    else
                                        results.add(0);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    int result;
                    try {
                        while (counter > 0) {
                            result = results.take();
                            counter--;
                            resultNP += result;
                        }
                    }catch (InterruptedException ie){
                        ie.fillInStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG,"results.take() failed");
                    }
                    callback.onCallback(resultNP);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    thread.setName("Firestore - numberGamesWherePlayerIsPresent()");
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that is related to Firestore?

Comment: @AlexMamo All functions that take a callback parameter are database calls, I will not put the code here because it is not useful but in general the function is just a Firestore.path.get.addOnCompleteListener ()